# Upgrade problem 12.04 to 14.04: screen blank on reboot, but recoverable

Tags: upgrade, screen, reboot

I upgraded my Ubuntu a couple of night ago. All went smoothly until the system restart step when the installation blanked the screen.  Clearly Ubuntu was running and after waiting long enough for full reboot I tried touching the top button on the computer and it all came to life offering me to close down or suspend (exactly as if the restart had been OK).  I closed the dialog box and all was then well.  But exactly the same thing happens on a normal reboot now.  This must be a relatively simple config error.  Can anyone tell me how to stop this annoying behaviour.

Cheers all, Colin  R

Answer (score 0):

The problem was traced to a failing monitor. Plugging in a newer monitor has fixed it. I recommend trying this for any blank screen problems with upgrades.